# Parallelization of brute force search algorithm with threading in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, search

I've been working on a brute force program in C++ that for the time being only deals with alpha numeric values (lower case only), and a password of unknown length.

I'm working with a quad core computer so I've broken the list of possibilities into four sections and have one thread working on each.

The sections are:

```
000...0 to 8zz...z
900...0 to hzz...z
i00...0 to qzz...z
r00...0 to zzz...z
```

Could I make better use of threading to increase the speed?  Since only 1 of 4 threads will ever reach the password it feels like 3/4 of the program is a waste of time.

It would seem that if I could have the threads work together somehow it would be more efficient, however I can't seem to think of a way to do this.

Any advice is much appreciated, I'm quite new to threading.

**EDIT: I should clarify that because it's a fairly simple program for academic purposes, I am actually only cracking one password, and giving the signal to kill the remaining 3 threads once one finds it. **

Comment: Well, if you know which quarter that is going to find the right password, then you could split that quarter and ignore the others...

Comment: Brute forcing **is** a *massive* waste of time, that's why you want to avoid it whenever possible. This is just an object example of how inefficient it is.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to create a deterministic search algorithm that always finds the password by searching only 25% of the search space.  This would be impossible.  Have all 4 processors work on one batch, and there is a 25% chance that you will find the password, but it will complete 4 times faster.

Comment: Well if one thread solves it before the other have reached halfway, the program doesn't have to run any more, so the effort saved is much less than the 3/4 you think.

Comment: Note that on some architectures, particularly Intel's Quad Core, you will get better performance with eight threads, even though there are only four physical cores.

Comment: Ah, thank you, Ian. I might try that then and see if it helps.
Sadly I've no way of knowing what quarter it'll be in, Mats. 
I might try to do that, Eric. Based on what section has the most letters used and just hope that one finds the password more often than the last one done. 
I hadn't thought of it that way, Joachim.

Comment: The whole point (or at least most of the point) of using a large password is to *force* you to search through this huge number of possibilities, knowing full-well that only *one* of them will be right, and many millions of others will be wrong. Finding a way to avoid a substantial part of that is pretty much the definition of breaking the encryption algorithm itself instead of brute-forcing the password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

- You can use an atomic boolean variable to communicate across the threads that the password has been found. Each thread just has to check periodically (for example, just before attempting the next password) if the flag has been set.
- Instead of statically dividing the work in four equal parts, you could also use one central list of passwords to try and let each thread grab items as they need it.

Comment: +1 for the second bullet. *Straggling processes* require you to do some extra work, otherwise you are most likely to be delayed by the straggling process, and 3 processors will be idle while calculating this task.

Comment: I must admit I haven't used atomic boolean variables before, but I'll look into it. Right now I have only the function checking the password returns true if it's correct.

The second bullet seems like a great idea too, especially if the threads are working at unequal speeds.

Comment: Even easier than communicating across the threads is to *exit* the process when the password is found.

Comment: @wallyk: That is rather drastic, especially if you wanted to do more after cracking that one password (for example, take on another one).

Comment: @Tyler: Instead of an atomic variable, you could also use a regular one that is protected by a mutex.

Comment: Or combine the two approaches: use a work queue (where each thread will take a work chunk once in a while). The queue is obviously a blocking queue to guarantee concurrency correct behavior. Once a thread found the password, it will just empty the queue, and all other threads will "know" it when they come to take the next chunk of data.

Comment: @amit That's a great idea. How I have it now I've four longest possibilities for any given number of digits. E.g. zzz, 8zz, hzz. Having each thread take a work chunk will cut down on how often they have to pull from the queue too.

Comment: @Tyler: Put batches in your queue. Have batches that take a small, but measurable amount of time to run, like 100-500ms or so. Then the overhead of the queue will not dominate the runtime. And the queue should have a way to empty it of all existing work units, so then you don't have to check an atomic bool every pass either, just end when the queue is empty and forcibly empty the queue as soon as one thread finds something. This will still do excess work, but only a minimal amount.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau:  Well, once the process exits, its parent can then do more work, like begin another child to crack a new password.  Using process level primitives is usually far simpler, more portable, and easier to extend than thread level footwork.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone. I came looking for a better method and found just that, so I'll mark it ans answered and get started on implementing people's ideas.

Answer (score 1):

for 4 threads this is as efficient as possible. No runtime is wasted, because with brute force you have to check all possibilities...

Comment: I am not sure I agree with the claim "as efficient as possible". If you will have *straggling processes* (and statistically speaking, you most likely will), while the straggling process works, the 3 other CPUs do nothing.. Splitting the data dynamically rather then statistically tend to help here (though it adds an overhead, and there is of course a trade-off, which one to chose, usually a good approach is to start with high chunks and reduce their size as closer you get to the end of the work).

Comment: @amit- yes, you are right, of course. I was referring to the '3/4 of the runtime is wasted' part. Dividing into differently sized parts is a good approach, I will do that next time..

Answer (score 0):

You can create one global `bool` variable, which will be `true` if some of the threads found right password ( you will set it to true if you found password), and check if it's set to true, for example, after trying every 1000 passwords in each thread. This will cut that not efficient iteration in threads, when other thread have already found right password.

*at start, you have to have this global variable set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a semaphore initialized to zero and a killer thread waiting on that semaphore. When a thread finds the answer, have it bump up the semaphore, unleashing the killer thread so that it can send the other threads to thread heaven.

It's the same as checking a global flag, only the global thread is checked in the kernel and not on every iteration but only on context switches.